# Swapping portions of text in a String in Java

Tags: java, string, swap

I currently have a String and I am looking to swap every 4 characters with another set of four characters. EG

Input: 1001 1101 0001 1001

Output:1101 1001 1001 0001

I really have no idea how to actually swap the characters. Would I do character by character, or is there some way that I could swap multiple ones at a time. Thanks very much! :)

Comment: Have you tried something like reading [the documentation of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see if there is anything there that might help you?

Comment: Your question is too vague

Answer (score 1):

String.replace() method would be appropriate I guess.

Answer (score 0):

String in Java are immutable, meaning you can't change them. If you want to do modifications like this, use StringBuilder instead. It has methods to get and replace substrings (in your case a substring of 4 characters).

API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string on spaces which would result in an array of Strings.

From there you could loop through each string and replace it to your desired result. After that is done, you can build it back into a string using `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "1001 1101 0001 1001";
//make array of strings in order to swap them, space being the common trait
String[] array = input.split("\\s");
//then swap array elements
for(int i = 0;i<array.length-1;i+=2){
   String tmp = array[i];
   array[i]= array[i+1];
   array[i+1] = tmp;
}
//build the output
String output = "";
for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
   if(i<array.length-1)
       output+= array[i] + " ";
   else
       output+= array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[StringBuilder.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) would be more appropriate than *String.replace()* since it does not copy the entire string.

Even better for performance a char[] may work well if you know the size of your string will be constant.  The *replace()* calls all shift the chars unnecessarily if you are always replacing a fix count of characters.

Finally Apache Commons has [StringUtils.overlay()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#overlay(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) and some other helpful String utils if you'd like to consider a third party library ( in case they'd help with other requirements )